# Associate One profile with a job (ror)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm developing an application where I have several profiles, company profiles and jobs.

The company can post a job, but I can't find a way where a Profile can apply for one job.

I need to associate the job with every profile that applied to it. I guess I would have to create a column on my Job so I can list every ID that applied for that job, but I don't know how to start doing that.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming Profiles can apply for more than one job, you could setup your associations up like this:

```
class CompanyProfile
  has_many :jobs, dependent: :destroy
end

class Job
  belongs_to :company_profile
  has_many :applications, dependent: :destroy
end

class Application
  belongs_to :profile
  belongs_to :job
end

class Profile
  has_many :applications, dependent: :destroy
end
```

I think this is very much open to discussion though and it also depends what you want your app to be able to do; there might be scope for some sort of :through relationship.

Comment: I like the idea of creating the class Application to manage it. I'll try that! Thank you!